# How to change WIX Heat.exe toolset version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, heat

I have Visual Studio WIX installation project which worked earlier with WIX 3.9, it does not work with WIX, after I installed new WIX 4.0.

```
ServerSetup.wixproj(67,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\Bin\Heat.exe" is invalid.
```

Line 67 from ServerSetup.wixproj project file is:

```
<HeatProject Project="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)" ProjectName="%(ProjectReference.Name)" OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)Harvested XML\_%(ProjectReference.Name).xml" ProjectOutputGroups="%(ProjectReference.RefProjectOutputGroups)" ToolPath="$(Wix)Bin\" SuppressAllWarnings="true" AutogenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressUniqueIds="false" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.FullPath)'!='' And '%(ProjectReference.DoNotHarvest)'!='True' And '%(ProjectReference.ImportedFromVDProj)'!='True'" />
```

I have already unistalled WIX 3.x and I have only Wix 4.0. What should I change to force Visual Studio 2013 to use WIX 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "WIX" environment variable pointing to C:\Program File (x86)\Wix Toolset v3.10\" ? I *think* this is how the heat location is being detected but since you no longer have 3.10 installed, the file doesn't exist.

Updating this environment variable may fix the issue for you. Alternatively you should be able to force your project to pick up the right heat dir by setting a few properties:

```
<WixRootPath Condition=" '$(WixRootPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Tools\wix\$(WixTargetVersion)\</WixRootPath>
<WixToolPath Condition=" '$(WixToolPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)</WixToolPath>
<WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)sdk\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
<WixTasksPath Condition=" '$(WixTasksPath)' == '' ">$(WixToolPath)WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
<WixSdkPath Condition=" '$(WixSdkPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)sdk\</WixSdkPath>
```

but ideally this should not be required on a machine where you already have wix installed. You can also try uninstalling wix 4.0 and reinstalling it which may magically fix everything. Just a repair may not work.

Comment: I have uninstall and reinstall WIX and WIX Project in Visual Studio stopped working at all. There is just message "The application is not installed."

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't done any work with wix 4.0 and my suggestions were just best guesses at something that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I uninstalled WIX 4, restarted computer and installed WIX 4 and now I can compile the project successfully.